# Detect if image is dark/light and addClass (dark/light) to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On this Fiddle, the functions does the job perfectly, but I need to tweak the junction slightly.

- the click even needs to be a addClass (dark/light)(true of false) to the parent div.
- If dark addClass Bright.
- If light image addClass dark.

Is there a way to make this function doing what I need?

```
getImageBrightness(this.src,function(brightness) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = "Brightness: "+brightness;
        });
```

jsfiddle.net/s7Wx2/

Comment: So add an if and add the class based on the value of the brightness variable.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I thought so, I can try but not sure I can do it.

Comment: What do you think is complicated? Break it up into twi steos. First use a basic `if/else` to get the classname to add. After that, it is adding the classname to the element

Comment: You need to determine what you consider the line between dark and light. It may be 255/2 => 127.5... Which is the straith half.... OR less... Depending on your judgement. Then compare.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette something like this??  if (x < imgs.length){
     $('pre').addClass('dark');
      $('pre').removeClass('light');
    }else{
    $('pre').removeClass('dark');
    $('pre').addClass('light');
    }

Comment: @user3699998 What's the purpose of `x < imgs.length`?  Remember, you are working with the variable `brightness` at this point.  It ranges from `0` to `255`.  `255 / 2` would be the halfway point.  Use that in your attempt to add the right class.  You have the right jQuery commands, though.  Also, btw, you can highlight code in comments by wrapping them in ` (backticks).

Comment: @JosephMarikle something like this? `if (brightness = 0){
     $('pre').addClass('dark');
      $('pre').removeClass('light');
    }
    else{
    $('pre').removeClass('dark');
    $('pre').addClass('light');
    }`

Comment: Pretty close.  You'll need to test against a range, however.  Remember that the brightness will be between 0 and 255.  You can accomplish this by checking if it's less than the halfway mark (which would be 128) or as an expression: `brightness < 256 / 2` (`brightness < 128` works too).

Comment: @JosephMarikle would you be able to check this on please http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wx2/110/

Comment: It's, again, pretty close.  Your code block for the check is in the wrong place, however.  It needs to be in the same scope as the `brightness` variable.  Try placing it inside the `getImageBrightness(this.src,function(brightness) { ... })` part.  Then it'll be in scope and should set your class like you're wanting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/k8w1jd37/)

In your HTML, I only added `id` to your `img`.
I played a little your pure javascript `getImageBrightness`... But not that much.

I used "127.5" as the middle line between dark and light.
I suggest you evaluate it... Since the human eye isn't as mathematical as scripts.
;)

Here is the script:

```
var thisImg;

function getImageBrightness(image,callback) {
    var thisImgID = image.attr("id");

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = image.attr("src");

    img.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    var colorSum = 0;

    img.onload = function() {
        // create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);

        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var data = imageData.data;
        var r,g,b,avg;

          for(var x = 0, len = data.length; x < len; x+=4) {
            r = data[x];
            g = data[x+1];
            b = data[x+2];

            avg = Math.floor((r+g+b)/3);
            colorSum += avg;
        }

        var brightness = Math.floor(colorSum / (this.width*this.height));
        callback(thisImgID, brightness);
    }
}

$("img").on("click", function(){
    thisImg = $(this)

    getImageBrightness( $(this),function( thisImgID, brightness ) {     
        document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = "Brightness: "+brightness+"<br><br>- Red border means class added -> dark,<br>- yellow border mean class added -> light";

        if(brightness<127.5){
            $("#"+thisImgID).addClass("dark");
        }else{
            $("#"+thisImgID).addClass("light");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.dark{
    border:3px solid red;
}
.light{
    border:3px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: I see no comment... Thanks this was very useful!